# I want to know how you can run Processing Code in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, processing

The ellipse that I have is for drawing a moon and everything else that says fill is for different colors. Basically my code animates different colored moving stars on a black background with a white moon below

```
void setup() { //only runs once    
  fullScreen();    
}    

void draw(){       
    {
    // black background
    fill (255);    

    // white circle(x,y,height,width)

    ellipse(800, 500, 500, 500);

    }
{
 //WHITE
  fill(0, 9);
  rect(0,0,width,height);
  fill(255); 
  noStroke();
  ellipse(random(width),random(height),3,3); 

  //GREEN
  fill(0,9);
  rect(0,0,width,height);    
  fill(0,250,9);     
  noStroke();    
  ellipse(random(width),random(height),5,5);

  //PURPLE
   fill(0,9);    
  rect(0,0,width,height);    
  fill(250,0,250);     
  noStroke();    
  ellipse(random(width),random(height),5,5);

  //BLUE      
   fill(0,9);    
  rect(0,0,width,height);    
  fill(0,255,255);     
  noStroke();    
  ellipse(random(width),random(height),5,5);
}

}
```

Comment: Do you mind add some explanation with your code ?

Comment: The ellipse that I have is for drawing a moon and everything else that says fill is for different colors. Basically my code animates different colored moving stars on a black background with a white moon below

Comment: When you add further details, edit your post, not all will read the comment

Comment: Also add a question in your post, a problem that you face

Comment: Please add question to your post detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Processing can be used as a Java library, and then you can use it from Eclipse just like you can use any other Java library.

You have to modify your code a bit though, since you lose out on the "magic" that the Processing editor does for you. Specifically, you have to create a class that extends `PApplet` and put your code in there.

Get something simple working before you try porting over your full sketch.

Here's an example:

```
import processing.core.PApplet;

public class MySketch extends PApplet {

    public void settings() {
        size(500, 500);
    }

    public void draw(){
        background(64);
        ellipse(mouseX, mouseY, 20, 20);
    }

    public static void main(String[] passedArgs) {
        String[] appletArgs = new String[] { "MySketch" };
        PApplet.main(appletArgs);
    }
}
```

Shameless self-promotion: [here](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/java/processing-in-java) is a guide on using Processing as a Java library.

Comment: @charmypatel You're welcome. Note that you can [accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it helped you.